# Ajax:unable to POST (404)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, post

POST Script in manage.ejs file i console logged the data its working there and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var guildID = "<%= guild.id %>";
  let data = {some valid json}
  $('.btn-primary.btn').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: `/dashboard/${guildID}/manage/save`,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                timeout: 5000,
                complete: function() {
                  //called when complete
                  console.log('process complete');
                },

                success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                  console.log('process sucess');
               }
              });
        })
</script>
```

dashboard.js i imported the body-parser am i missing something in /save other all post are working too

```
 var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  app.use(bodyParser.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
  })); 

app.get("/dashboard/:guildID/save", checkAuth, async (req, res) => {
    const guild = client.guilds.get(req.params.guildID);
    if (!guild) return res.status(404);
    res.contentType('json');
   console.log(req.body)

    res.redirect("/dashboard/"+req.params.guildID);
  });
```

Comment: It looks like you are posting to: `/dashboard/${guildID}/manage/save` but only listening on `/dashboard/:guildID/save`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting to: `/dashboard/${guildID}**/manage/save**` but serving on the endpoint `/dashboard/:guildID**/save**`